# strsplit returns empty string with regex

Tags: regex, r

In R, I have a variable Author, with the value "(Bernoulli)Cuatrec."

I want to have only the names, so I'm using the following regex:

```
L <- strsplit(Author,"[()]")
```

but that's giving me 3 strings as result:

```
""          "Bernoulli" "Cuatrec."
```

How can I do it to have only the two names, and not the empty string?

PS: My actual regex is more complicated, it's simplified here.

Comment: Try `library(stringr);str_extract_all(Author, '[^()]+')[[1]]`

Comment: You could also try the `stringi` package `stri_split_regex(Author, "[()]", omit_empty = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

In the solutions below set `rmChars` and `splitChars` (for the first solution) and `chars` (for the second solution) to a pattern representing the actual sets of characters you need to use.  Depending on your words and non-words you might be able to use built in classes such as `chars <- "\\W"` which sets `chars` to all non-word characters.

**1)** Remove the ( first and then split on ) .  Assuming `s` is the input string:

```
rmChars <- "[(]"
splitChars <- "[)]"
strsplit(gsub(rmChars, "", s), splitChars)[[1]]
```

giving:

```
[1] "Bernoulli" "Cuatrec."
```

**2)** Another possibility is to replace each character in `chars` with a space, trim the ends and then split on space.

```
chars <- "[()]"
strsplit(trimws(gsub(chars, " ", s)), " ")[[1]]
```

giving:

```
[1] "Bernoulli" "Cuatrec."
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have more separators than just (). My actual regex is strsplit(Author,"[ 众古在未()&,;]{1,}"). Maybe I should have put it all in the question?

Comment: OK.  I have modularized it.

Comment: What's the earliest R version for `trimws`? First time seeing  it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to avoid installing new libraries, whenever possible. Thus, I can do just:

```
L <- strsplit(Author,"[()]")[[1]]
L <- L[which(L != "")]
```

I thought there would be a solution without the need for a library.

Comment: `stringr` is based on `stringi` and is C-backed. It's super-fast and deals with character sets better. "Minimal" is _not_ always better.

Answer (score 0):

If your data have always the same pattern, you can just use this:

```
strsplit(Author,"[[:punct:]]")[[1]][-1]
[1] "Bernoulli" "Cuatrec"
```

Of course if the pattern is irregular my solution is useless.